# Azure websites staging, caching and sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

We have our .NET website on Azure websites and have just enabled staging. For our session state we are using the Azure Cache preview. My question is will having my site on a staging environment and a production environment have any effect on the sessions, i.e. Could I ever get duplicate sessions between the two sites?

Thanks

Comment: No, they will use different sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that it will not duplicate. But if you'll need, you can share cached objects between cloud services.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg278356.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh914133.aspx

Comment: Hi Thiago, thanks. I did some more reading and, if my memory serves me correctly, found that the session id created is a random 24 character string, so I don't see conflicts arising.